# How to chose scale for continuous wavelet transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, wavelet

I'm trying to use a continuous wavelet transform but I keep getting `ValueError: Only dim == 1 supported.`  My data is a pandas dataframe.

I have tried using the following:

`df2 = py.cwt(df, scales=1, wavelet='gaus1')`

My results were the

```
ValueError: only dim == 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-4c0398b4c4f3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/user_1/untitled6.py', wdir='/home/user_1')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/user_1/untitled6.py", line 41, in <module>
    df2 = py.cwt(df,scales ,wavelet='gaus1')

  File "/home/user_1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywt/_cwt.py", line 107, in cwt
    raise ValueError("Only dim == 1 supported")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pywt.cwt()` offers the **One dimensional** Continuous Wavelet Transform. When working with Pandas, you can apply it on a Series, but not on a Dataframe.